# Use pjsua without sound device

Tags: pjsip

We are implementing sip client on embedded chip and there is a problem to make voice call. pjsua printed error message on screen:

```
    Press a to answer or h to reject call
a
Answer with code (100-699) (empty to cancel): 200
20:19:00.811           pjsua_call.c !Answering call 0: code=200
20:19:00.811          pjsua_media.c  ...Call 0: updating media..
20:19:00.811          pjsua_media.c  ....pjmedia_stream_info_from_sdp() failed for call_id 0 media 0: Invalid media payload type (PJMEDIA_EINVALIDPT)
20:19:00.811          pjsua_media.c  .....Media stream call00:0 is destroyed
20:19:00.811          pjsua_media.c  ....Error updating media call00:0: Invalid media payload type (PJMEDIA_EINVALIDPT)
20:19:00.811           pjsua_call.c  ...Unable to create media session: No active media stream after negotiation (PJMEDIA_SDPNEG_ENOMEDIA) [status=220048]
20:19:00.811           pjsua_core.c  ......TX 657 bytes Response msg 488/INVITE/cseq=5078 (tdta0x55ff190ff418) to UDP 91.121.209.194:5060:
SIP/2.0 488 Not Acceptable Here
```

I started the pjsua sample with following command line(x86 pjsua):

```
$ ./pjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --null-audio --local-port=15060
```

Does pjsua forcely check sound device? We just want to make call and transmit external DSP audio data to server, and we have already implemented fetching audio data from local DSP. Is there any way to send audio via pjsua without modify source code of pjsip? Our pjsip version is 2.8.

PS: I have read the document and it told me several ways to achieve our goal.

method 1:
set_null_audio_device

method 2:
enable external sound device (We have no idea how it works)

method 3:
third party media sample (pjsip 2.X, a little bit complicated)

method 4:
integrating third party media stack (pjsip 1.X only?)

but none of them has sample program. some methods are even deprecated.